std::map::find finds non-existing key
I'm trying to get iterator by some key using a std::map::find method. However, I get some valid iterator, but it's first value of pair corresponding to map's key does not exist in map. Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <map>
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>,bool> points;
    std::array<std::map<std::pair<int,int>,bool>::iterator, 4> prev_iter;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    points[{x,y}] = false;

    prev_iter[0] = points.find({x-4, y});
    std::cout <<  prev_iter[0]->first.first <<" , "
    <<  prev_iter[0]->first.second ;
}

I enter 2 integers 4 5 , and the output is 1 , 0, but key (1,0) does not exist in points. What is the reason for such behaviour?
I expected to get points.end(), because this key does not exist in points.

you MUST check that the return of find is != map.end(), using it when it is equal to that value is undefined behavior, this means the value is not found.

It probably does point to end, but you never check that and just access the iterator, which has undefined behavior.

@eagerbeaver04 Your code, when run under Visual C++ debug build, shows a "debug assertion error".   This is what undefined behavior is all about, as it didn't even get to output any information.  So what you "expected" becomes a moot point.

"I expected to get points.end(), " you do. Why do you think you do not?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai The likely culprit is the misunderstading of what the end iterator represents.

Wait until you find out that map's [] operator creates default-constructed items when the key's not found.

When map.find() doesn't find the value in the map, it returns map.end(), which points "nowhere". Using this iterator when it points to nowhere is undefined behavior. Best case is the app crashes, worst case is the app keeps working in a wrong state and produce garbage. Always check against .end():
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> map{{4,5}};
    const auto it = map.find(1);
    if (it != map.end())
    {
        std::cout << "value " << it->second <<  " found!" << '\n';
    } 
    else
    {
        std::cout << "value not found!" << '\n';
    }
}


value not found

